# Android SQL query not recognizing first entry

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

Buckle up folks, this is a weird one. I'm currently working on an android app that involves storing and retrieving data in an sqlite database. I was going through the app and testing some of the basic features to make sure everything worked, and lo and behold I found a bug in retrieving data from my database. When a user inputs their very first entry to the app, everything works as expected, the values get processed and stored. However, when I go back and attempt to access that data using `SELECT * FROM history;` I get a cursor that returns true when I call `data.moveToNext()`, yet when I loop through it using `while(data.moveToNext()) { //get values and add to a List<> }` the while loop never gets executed.

I've looked at the contents of the database after moving the file to my computer and opening the database using [this](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) db browser and I can see my entry.

Here's the method that I call to get all the points from my database:

```
List<PointValue> getAllPoints() {
    List<PointValue> points;
    Cursor data = rawQuery("SELECT * FROM history");
    if (data.moveToNext()) {
        points = new ArrayList<>();
        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            System.out.println("Looped");
            long timestamp = data.getLong(data.getColumnIndexOrThrow("timestamp"));
            int level = data.getInt(data.getColumnIndexOrThrow("level"));
            points.add(new PointValue(timestamp, level));
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    data.close();
    if (points.size() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return points;
}
```

The `rawQuery` method looks like this:

```
private Cursor rawQuery(String sql) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    return db.rawQuery(sql, null);
}
```

When I tried debugging this on my own, the size of `points` is 0 even though I *know* that there's at least one point in the database. Thoughts? The class containing all of my sql related stuff extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`

EDIT:
Here's the solution suggested by @Isaac Payne (still doesn't work):

```
public List<PointValue> getAllPoints() {
    List<PointValue> points = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor data = rawQuery("SELECT * FROM history");

    while (data.moveToNext()) {
        long timestamp = data.getLong(data.getColumnIndexOrThrow("timestamp"));
        int level = data.getInt(data.getColumnIndexOrThrow("level"));
        points.add(new PointValue(timestamp, level));
    }
    data.close();
    if (points.size() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return points;
}
```

Comment: If you log data.getCount() do you get 1 entry?

Comment: @IsaacPayne Just realized that I was debugging the entirely wrong method, I edited the correct method as you suggested, and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that when you call `data.moveToNext()` in the if statement you are moving to the first entry, then you call `moveToNext()` again in your while loop moving to the second non-existent entry. Try removing the if statement

Comment: If there's a method that returns the number of records in the response, you can use `if (data.numRecords() > 0)` in place of that.

Comment: No luck, the updated method is at the bottom of my original question

Answer (score 0):

Add data.moveToFirst() before if loop.

```
Cursor data = rawQuery("SELECT * FROM history");
//add this line
data.moveToFirst();
if (data.moveToNext()) {
```